# Are U.S government bonds completely liquid?

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds

In the event of a market downturn like 2008, could I liquidate them whenever I wanted to at good price on a retail stock broker?

Comment: Note that selling during a downturn is a Bad Idea.

Comment: @RonJohn what if the selling of bonds is to free up capital take advantage of even lower equity prices?

Answer (score 3):

> Are U.S government bonds completely liquid?

A liquid asset is anything that can be sold quickly.  US Government Bonds are **very** liquid.

> In the event of a market downturn like 2008, could I liquidate them whenever I wanted to

Yes.

> at good price

<s>Probably not</s> Maybe.  After all, price is a function of *supply*
and *demand*.

During the 2008 meltdown, "everyone" was selling stocks, so there was a large *supply*, and low *demand*.  Thus, prices fell.

The bond market was affected because some traders needed cash quickly to satisfy loans, and so had to sell their bonds to raise that cash.  That increased supply meant... lower prices.

Thus, the answer to "at good price?" is <s>not really</s> maybe.

> on a retail stock broker?

Yes, as long as they are the custodians.

Comment: "In the event of a market downturn like 2008", T-Bond prices were "really good", like 15-25% capital gains.

Comment: @base64 was that *during* the collapse, or *afterward*?  (I know the Fed dropped interest rates *afterwards* to stimulate liquidity.)

Comment: @RonJohn Look at a TLT chart. There was no unusual downward volatility in Treasury bonds during 2008. There was, however, unusual upward volatility in Nov and Dec.

Comment: Interesting.  This makes sense but this makes most publicly traded stocks liquid as well.  I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: @base64 I would like to know this as well.